# Postgres asking for password after install that does not match install password

Tags: windows, postgresql

After I install Postgres 12 on my windows machine and try to log in in the command line using: `psql`

I am prompted for a password. I enter the password that I used during the install, but it is rejected by Postgres with the message:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"

username is actually my windows username.

I have tried:

- uninstalling Postgres with and without deleting the Postgres folder, and then doing a fresh re-install.
- editing the pg_hba file and putting "trust" at the end of every line
- using the windows password

Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: The password you gave is likely for the postgres user.  Try specifying the username when you connect.

Answer (score 4):

The password you entered during installation is for the `postgres` database user, the superuser that was created with the database cluster.

But the default value for the database user name when you run `psql` is the same as the operating system user.

So unless you are logged in as the `postgres` operating system user, you have to specify the username explicitly:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Will get the same error.

Comment: @Reimirno No, you will get a different error. At least, the user name in the error message will be different.